# Problemas al guardar src imagen en localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Esta es mi página html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/miestilos.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
    <input type="file" id="files"  />
    <output id="list"></output>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/app.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Y mi script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='';
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="center" id="imagen" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);


      localStorage.setItem("imgSrc",document.getElementById('imagen').src);

    };
  })(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
}
 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
});
```

Necesito guardar el src de la imagen para cuando vaya a una Pagina.html diferente pueda pintar esta imagen en canvas y manipularla.

Para ciertas imagenes funciona pero para imagenes grandes me salta este error al hacer la instruccion " localStorage.setItem("imgSrc",document.getElementById('imagen').src);":

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'imgSrc' exceeded the quota.

Entiendo que el src es demasiado extenso como para guardarlo en localStorage.

Lo que hago en la otra página es lo siguiente :
var imgSrc=localStorage.getItem("imgSrc");

var img=new Image();

img.src=imgSrc;

Me funciona para imagenes pero para otras me da fallo al guardar el src en el storage.

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecería. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el localStorage está limitado a 5Mb, y seguramente el contenido de la imagen en base64 ocupe más que esto o tengas otros elementos en el localStorage que, junto con la imagen, ocupen más del limite.

Tal vez puedas reducir las dimensiones de la imagen con alguna librería (para que ocupe menos) antes de guardarla en el localStorage.  Acá tenés un ejemplo de como hacerlo: https://zocada.com/compress-resize-images-javascript-browser/.

Otra posibilidad sería la de enviarla en un post a la otra página y volver a escribir el src de la imagen en el HTML de la página destino, pero va a generar mucho tráfico innecesario.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es amplifyJS. Quizás de algo más de juego, ya que te permite cambiar entre diferentes tecnologías (localStorage, sessionStorage, globalStorage, userData, memory).

Cambiará ligeramente la sintaxis con la que guardas ahora en localStorage...

Por ejemplo:

**Para guardar**

```
amplify.store("id_img", "http://");
```

**Para borrar**

```
amplify.store("id_img", null);
```

**Para listarlos**

```
amplify.store();
```

Mas ejemplos y documentación oficial: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store